# What is the Latest URL Scheme to open an youtube channel from iOS app

Tags: ios, youtube

I want to open Youtube app with an channel from my iPhone app. Previously i was using the following URL scheme and it was working fine.

**youtube://user/channel Name**.

But this is not working after i updated my Youtube app to 2.6.0 which is latest. Is there any change in the URL scheme to open youtube app with a channel. Any help would be appreciated.

i tried with the following but of no use.

**youtube://channel/channelName**

**youtube://channel/channelID**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe this should be marked as a duplicate as the question is specifically asking for the scheme to open the youtube app at a specific channel.  The question in the marked duplicate is for opening a search term and does not mention a channel at all.

Comment: Question followed by the link partly resolve the task, but there is no the direct solution. So, you just type "youtube://www.youtube.com/channel/\(channelID)" to open in the app. I.e enter  "youtube://" + a link to utube

Answer (score 13):

youtube://www.youtube.com/user/channelname

Comment: I was skeptical at first because of the weird format and domain but, this worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me: youtube://www.youtube.com/channel/channelName (Youtube v10.49.13)

Answer (score 0):

Native app URL strings:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_IDENTIFIER

http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_IDENTIFIER

Please refer this [Apple Doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH8-SW1) for more info.

Comment: hi Natarajan, Thanks for the response. But these are not working and i want to open a page not an video.