# app schema for Youtube channel

Tags: ios, youtube, deep-linking

I've tried the app schema written in [this page](http://pureoxygenlabs.com/10-app-url-schemes-for-marketers/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541470/what-is-the-latest-url-scheme-to-open-an-youtube-channel-from-ios-app), but it's not working.
Does anyone know the app schema for a Youtube channel?

Comment: are you sure YouTube app is installed on the same device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing (in Safari), you can do:

`youtube:///user/username`